# How to show camera input on screen using java and opencv for Android app development?

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I want show camera input on screen using java and opencv for Android app development. Is there an opencv functions that i can use?

Comment: What do you mean by `screen`?

Comment: the home page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html). It gives detailed instructions on how to setup OpenCV for Android development. You can download version 2.4.9 of the OpenCV SDK from Source Forge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.9/). There are a number of sample android applications in the SDK that make use of the Android Camera.